# How to get the Design Last modified date of the Database using Lotus Script?

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript

I want to get the Design Last modified(Not Database modified) date of the database using lotus script. I can get the Design last modified date from the catalog.nsf, But I need to take it from the database.

Comment: Please update your question to include the code you use to get the database modified date as reference and anything else you have tried

Answer (score 2):

Look in database for every design element when it was last modified and take the most recent.
You can get all design elements with `NotesNoteCollection`. As design elements are NotesDocuments you can get the last modified date with `doc.LastModified`.

This is an example for an agent where you can choose a database and get printed the design last modified date:

```
Dim workspace As New NotesUIWorkspace
Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim nid As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim doc As NotesDocument
Dim designLastModified As Variant
Dim serverDatabase As variant

serverDatabase = workspace.Prompt(13, "Choose Database", "") 
If IsEmpty(serverDatabase) Then Exit Sub
Set db = session.Getdatabase(serverDatabase(0), serverDatabase(1), false)

Dim nc As NotesNoteCollection
Set nc = db.CreateNoteCollection(False)
Call nc.SelectAllDesignElements(True)
Call nc.BuildCollection

designLastModified = 0

nid = nc.GetFirstNoteId
For i = 1 To nc.Count
    Set doc = db.GetDocumentByID(nid)
    If Not doc Is Nothing then
        If designLastModified < doc.LastModified Then
            designLastModified = doc.LastModified
        End If
    End if
    nid = nc.GetNextNoteId(nid)
Next

Print "Design last modified: " & designLastModified
```

It prints exactly the time shown in field "Design last modified date:" in catalog.nsf for selected database.

Comment: Thanks Knut Herrmann. It is working fine as expected. But you have used Loop (For& If). Is there any other way to get that without looping?

Comment: No, you have to check **all** design elements. So, a loop in some way is necessary. There is no property "Design last modified date" in database itself. You could read the value from catalog.nsf but I think that wasn't your goal.